# Maintaining old laptop HDD as backup while replacing with newer SSD

Tags: hard-drive, mac, backup, external-hard-drive, macbook-pro

**tl;dr:** Is it possible to replace an old hard drive while maintaining the existing bootable drive as an external backup?

Here is the story: I have a 10+ year old Apple Macbook Pro that **still works and boots** normally without issues (it is slow, but that's OK). I would like to keep the current (old school, spinning) HDD for posterity's sake. I have already backed it up, etc., and I realize this is an alternative (sub-par) solution, but that is not what I am specifically looking to do in this case.

What I'd like to do is replace the old HDD with a new SSD (e.g. using the instructions here: https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-unibody-faq/macbook-pro-13-15-17-mid-2009-how-to-upgrade-hard-drive-ssd.html), **while keeping the old HDD bootable from an external enclosure**. So, I would like to:

1. Migrate the old HDD into an enclosure (say, like this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-Tool-free-Enclosure-Optimized-EC-UASP/dp/B00OJ3UJ2S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OJ3UJ2S))
2. Install a new SSD into the old Macbook,
3. Re-install MacOS onto the new SSD,
4. Be able to access my old files from the old HDD using the external USB enclosure.

I have found lots of tutorials on how to clone an existing drive, but that is **not** what I want. I want to leave my old, still perfectly functioning drive accessible while getting a fresh install onto the old laptop. Before I attempt this, I am wondering if this is even possible, and if anyone who has tried this might have any pointers.

Comment: Install new drive, install OS on it. Done. Migration of settings is possible at first boot. btw, your old external drive will not be a backup, it will just be external storage, with the potential to also be a boot drive. A backup is an **additional** storage location.

Comment: So you're saying there will be no issues booting onto the external HDD, e.g. by booting from USB?

Comment: None whatsoever.

Comment: If you want to post this as an answer, I will accept it. Even though your answer is simple and straightforward, this situation does not seem to be well documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS will boot from ay bootable drive, internal or external (though there are restrictions possible on newer T2 equipped Mac, this doesn't apply to Macs before about 2017).

This means that you can simply remove your boot drive, drop it in an external enclosure & boot from it. If you replace the internal drive & install an OS you can then choose which to boot from, either from System Prefs or by holding  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  at boot.
This ability extends to any Mac capable of booting to the OS on that disk, not just the Mac the disk was removed from. This capability is essentially because macOS is pre-loaded with all drivers from all Macs capable of running that particular version of the OS, so swapping drives or even swapping Macs is totally seamless.

Once you have your new drive & OS installed, at first boot you will be given the option to migrate data &/or settings from an older system.
Once migration is successful you can choose whether or not to keep the data also on the original drive or delete it - this includes the old system if you no longer need it.

Note that it doesn't class as a backup if data exists in only one location.